# The matrix created by two arrays does not have expected dimensions

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Here is my first question and I am totally newby in Python so bear with me!

I am developing a code and at this step I am trying to create a matrix with 2 rows and certain amount of columns. The first row is an array and the second is another array (with the same length), UaP and UbP as can be seen in the code hopefully.
As it can be seen UaP and UbP both are (1, 400), but when I try to create an array by combining two, the resulted matrix dimension will be (2,1,400) instead of expected 2 x 400 dimension.
I have tried different things but I dont get what I expected. Maybe there is a simple trick to solve it? Thanks in advance.

````
```python
````

import numpy as np

```
#some codes here
UaP = 0.5*(Ua-Ub90)
UbP = 0.5*(Ub+Ua90)
UabP = np.array([(UaP),(UbP)])
# shapes of arrays
UbP.shape
(1, 400)
UaP.shape
(1, 400)
UabP = np.array([(UaP),(UbP)])
UabP.shape
(2, 1, 400)
```

Comment: try `np.vstack([UaP, UbP])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because your first array has shape `(1,400)` instead of `(400,)`.
You could try this:

```py
import numpy as np

UaP = np.random.rand(1,400)
UbP = np.random.rand(1,400)

# first solution
UabP = np.array([UaP[0],UbP[0]])
print(UabP.shape)

# second soluton
UabP = np.array([UaP,UbP])
UabP = UabP.reshape(1,2,400)
UabP = UabP[0]
print(UabP.shape)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for quick answer and concise explanation. Now I understand what was the problem The second solution solved my problem.